XCUI continue test loop even when fail
I'm running a test that launch a list of bundleID one by one and check if a specific button exist in the app. My current issue is when one app does not have the button -> test fail, but then the test stops checking the next bundleID.
How do I make the test continue checking the next bundleID?
Here is what I have now
func testLaunchApp() {
    let bundles = ["com.App1", "com.App2", "com.App3", "com.App4"]
    for bundle in bundles {
        XCContext.runActivity(named: "Test launching \(bundle)") { activity in
            setUp()
            testToBeLoop(bundle: bundle)
            tearDown()
        }
    }
}


func testToBeLoop(bundle: String){
    let app = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: bundle)
    app.launch()

    let theButton = app.button["myButton"]
    let isVisible = theButton.waitForExistence(timeout: 1)
    XCTAssert(isVisible, "Button is not visible)
}

Currently, if "com.App3" failed the Assert, the test will stopped without checking "com.App4" next.

You're going to want your test class to inherit from XCTestCase and then you'll set the continueAfterFailure property to true. More information available in the Apple docs.
